# Jenkins Declarative pipeline as code script error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

When i run multibranch pipeline code in jenkins i get the below error for the following [`Jenkinsfile`](https://github.com/Viyaan/jenkins-ci-cd/blob/master/Jenkinsfile):

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    // ...
```

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, error, fileExists, getContext, git, input, isUnix, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, parallel, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, retry, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tool, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, batchFile, booleanParam, buildButton, buildDiscarder, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, choice, choiceParam, clock, cloud, command, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, envVars, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, git, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, installSource, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, junit, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, myView, nodeProperties, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, run, runParam, schedule, scm, scmRetryCount, search, security, shell, slave, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, env, params, scm]

What could be wrong in my pipeline code or jenkins configuration?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are running an older version of the Pipeline plugin collection (provided via the [`workflow-aggregator`](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator) plugin older than version 2.5) and thus have not installed the plugin that implements declarative pipelines: "Pipeline: Declarative" [`pipeline-model-definition`](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-model-definition)

Comment: Thank you stephen king.

Comment: If this helped you, then please mark this thread is solved using the check mark.